# Automate adding multiple "sections" to the manifest?

Tags: java, ant, manifest

I'm using ant to generate the `MANIFEST.MF` for a .jar, and I need to add multiple manifest `<section>` blocks based on a list of files in a directory. However, I need to automate the process to do this at build-time since the list will change between development and deployment.

For example:

```
<manifest file="MANIFEST.MF">
  <foreach files="./*">
    <section name="section">
      <attribute name="Attribute-Name" value="$file"/>
    </section>
  </foreach>
</manifest>
```

I've looked at `foreach` from Ant-contrib but it doesn't look like it will work in this instance.

Is this possible?

Comment: What do you mean by sections?

Comment: could you possibly insert an example manifest output for, say, two input files in the incoming directory?  (I'm specifically wondering whether you want the section name to be the same for each file, or something else?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with the [Manifest task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/manifest.htmlfalse)

```
<manifest file="MANIFEST.MF">
    <section name="section">
        <attribute name="Attribute-Name" value="value"/>
    </section>
    <section name="section/class1.class">
        <attribute name="Second-Attribute-Name" value="otherValue"/>
    </section>
</manifest>
```

It will generate this manifest :

> Manifest-Version: 1.0
>   Created-By: Apache Ant 1.7
>
> Name: section
>   Attribute-Name: value
>
> Name: section/class1.class
>   Second-Attribute-Name: otherValue

You can maintain two different custom tasks to handle the different cases, and call the right one at the right moment.

---

For an "automatic" management :

```
<target name="manifest-generation">
    <foreach param="file" target="manifest">
        <path>
            <fileset dir=".">
                <include name="**/*.class"/>
            </fileset>
        </path>
    </foreach>
</target>

<target name="manifest">
    <manifest file="MANIFEST.MF" mode="update">
        <section name="${file}">
            <attribute name="Attribute-Name" value="value"/>
        </section>
    </manifest>
</target>
```

Comment: if this is not flexible enough, then you most probably need to write your own custom task

Comment: Yes, I know I can do it manually, but that's not what I'm asking. I'm asking how to **automate** adding multiple sections based on files in the filesystem.

Comment: Then what do you mean by "automate"? What result do you want?

Comment: Thanks colin! With some tweaks I've got that working how I need it.

Comment: @digitala, glad it worked. But be careful with the `mode="update"` you might want to remove the manifest file from time to time (or you'll keep old data)

Comment: @Colin: yep, in another section I'm always creating a new file, prepending some items, then using your example to update multiple sections. Cheers!